# Mysql connects but Mysqli shows no file or directory error

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

after updating my myqsli driver function i keep seeing this

```
     A PHP Error was encountered
    Severity: Warning

    Message: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory

    Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

    Line Number: 110

    Backtrace:

    File: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/alcantara/application/controllers/Vendor.php
    Line: 11
Function: __construct

File: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/alcantara/index.php
Line: 274
Function: require_once
```

I don't know if there is anything I have to install again, I am using mac os.
Here is my database file

```
*/

$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;
$db['default']['hostname'] = '127.0.0.1';
$db['default']['username'] = 'testing';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'database';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['socket'] = 'mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/project_id:xxx';
```

Comment: just add any password to `$db['default']['password']` and check it..

Comment: after resolving the issue , i discovered is mysqli that is not connecting but mysql connects

Comment: It mean `mysqli` extention not activate for your php script. add `phpinfo()` in your php file and run.... it will show loaded extention.. check it there is a mysqli extetion available or not.

Comment: is it your localhost or server .?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it buy updating my codeigniter mysqli connect function with the new one i downloaded from the website..